# Cannot get my promise to return in nodejs / mongoose / bluebird

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose, promise, bluebird

I'm using bluebird.

I've also used bluebird's Promisify for the models.

```
var Promise = require('bluebird');
var mongoose = Promise.promisifyAll(require('mongoose')); 
var Collection = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/collection'));
var Vote = Promise.promisifyAll(require('../models/vote'));
```

throughout my project, it has been working successfully, but for some reason, I cannot get it to return the collections value on this 'save' method.

Here is my model:

```
var CollectionSchema = new mongoose.Schema({
  user : {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'User', required: true},
  whiskey : {type: mongoose.Schema.ObjectId, ref: 'Whiskey', required: true},
  favorite: {type: Boolean, default: false},
  timestamp: { type : Date, default: Date.now }
});

    CollectionSchema.statics.createCollection = function(o) {
      console.log('hit model')
        return Collection
        .findAsync(o)
        .then(function(existing) {
          console.log('existing collection ', existing)
          if (existing.length) {
            return{
              message: 'already collected'
            }
          } else {
            console.log('no existing collections found')
           return Collection
            .saveAsync(o)
            .then(function(collection) {
              console.log('new collection / does not console.log ', collection)
              return {
                collection: collection
              };
            });
          }
        })
      };
```

Here is the controller, where the collectionCreate method is invoked and expecting a response 'data' from the promise. However, the saveAsync mongoose method does not seems to invoke or return :

```
exports.create = function(req, res){
  console.log('init')
  console.log('init body ', req.body)
  Collection.createCollectionAsync({user: req.user._id, whiskey: req.body.whiskey}).then(function(data){
    console.log('collection promise ', data)
    res.send(data);
  })
};
```

I could really use a second set of eyes to point out where I went wrong.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are not supposed to use the `…Async` promisified versions of functions that already return promises. That will only lead to Bluebird passing in an additional callback that is never called.

```
Collection.createCollection({user: req.user._id, whiskey: req.body.whiskey}).then(function(data){
    res.send(data);
}, function(err) {
    …
})
```

Comment: Makes sense. Thanks again, @Bergi. I owe you for helping me wrap my head around this.